# Caching Django page for fast loading

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I used Per-Site cache method to make fast when I load a page. In settings.py I did the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',     
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',  
]


CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'  
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = '604800'    
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
```

but what is happening is that when I make a change on database table, I cannot see the effect in the front end. But going back in the database it is fine. For example I change the name from Peter to Mary, on my template I still see Peter but in the database there is Mary. It seems that I need to synch my cache and the database.
Below is what I found over internet, but I do not know where to place this function. is in in views.py? in models? or anywhere else? Please assist

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def clear_cache(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if instance.published_on is not None:
    cache.delete('feed')
```

Comment: "when I make a change on database table, I cannot see the effect in the front end" <-- This exactly is the reason why caching makes your pages faster. Django _doesn't_ query the database for every request. If you don't want that you shouldn't use caching.

Comment: So isn't any other way I can use so that I use caching have django query database? at in in a small amount of time?